# Select element in shadow-root with css only

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom

is there any way how can I change CSS inside shadow-root without using JS I mean CSS only. I looked through some things but cant find a way how to do it without js.

lets say we have code

```
<div id="parent">
   #shadow-root (open)
     <div id="child">
     </div>
</div>
```

how can I access child with CSS only?

Answer (score 1):

Only if the component author explicitly allows it using the `part` attribute on the element in the shadow DOM. In that case you can apply CSS to that element using the [`::part` pseudo element selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part):

Here's an example:

```js
customElements.define('foo-bar', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = '<p part="baz">foo-bar here</p>';
  }
});
```

```css
::part(baz) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<foo-bar></foo-bar>
```

Please note that you can not do something like `::part(foo) + .internal-css-class {...}` (`::part` cannot be part of a compound selector).

Other than that, you can always work with CSS's inherited properties, these also affect the shadow DOM. E.g. putting the web component into an `<h1>` will affect it's font-size and -weight (unless it specifically defines its own values for those properties).